# Google Search to link to a Query String

Tags: seo, google, sitemap

How to get Google Search to link to a Query String for your page when no physical page Exist.

I notice when I do a google search for some keywords I get back some website hits that do **not** link to a physical page but instead redirect me to their search page with my google search terms pre-populated.

For instance if I search  "visualforce component blog" 
One of the  google results is http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/?s=visualforce+component+blog

How do I do this? Make the google search result link to a query string (dymanic search on my page) Is it via a siteMap entry ? Or something else?

Comment: @John Conde - could you please reopen this question as I have now clarified what I am asking

Answer (score 1):

- The site shows up for Salesforce searches because he's written about it consistently for years, and having also written a book on it is probably at least a bit of a reference point. He's presumably put in some SEO work on top of all that, and some basic digging in Google will show you he's linked all over the place. You're seeing the results of that effort.
- As for the search pages showing in Google results, it may have something to do with Google [using some sites' search forms](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/04/crawling-through-html-forms.html) to crawl data.
- The search form being populated with the terms isn't terribly interesting. He uses WordPress, which makes it easy to do that. Go to http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/?s=whatever+random+words and they'll be in there, too.
- I'm confused by your last example, as the search terms are *all over* that page you linked to, at least when I visit it.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes I guess I did not ask my question very well.. I guess what I was trying to ask was how does he get the Page Link form google to contain  xxx.com/?example+of+a+visualforce+component  etc. And why does google not link to a physical page.  Does he just have a site map setting?  Or does google crawler perform a search on his site for those terms?

Comment: I have now updated my question to match this comment. But I think your answer still applies. but I would like a little more detail